# VueJS with nginx redirection not working and returns 200 with blank page

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router

I uploaded VueJS SPA with history mode to the test server which uses nginx. The regular approach is to write these lines in your nginx config file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

however I tried and after I try to access some dummy URL, it doesn't redirect me back to my `index.html` file as expected and instead it shows a blank page with status code 200. I would like to redirect user to index.html.

Just want to mention that I restart server every time I make some change.

---

Here are some of my files:
name: "default" (nginx config), specifically the part with the project

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/ux-assessment/dist;
    index index.html;
    server_name 9a6bc157c174d32178c0e3b92b963394.p4m-dev.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

router.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import ThankYouModal from './components/ThankYouModal.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'thank-you',
          component: ThankYouModal,
          name: 'thankYouModal'
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
})
```

- path to dist folder in FTP is correct
- vue.config.js is empty

  ---

so if you try to go to [9a6bc157c174d32178c0e3b92b963394.p4m-dev.com/foo](http://9a6bc157c174d32178c0e3b92b963394.p4m-dev.com/foo) it should redirect you to `index.html` but it does not and stays on the subpage `/foo` with code status 200 and a blank page. The page is live so you can try it and look inside inspector => network.

I tried also another approaches but nothing worked. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the page is blank? It might be your index.html page but with no route matching. Nginx is not returning balnk pages, it would give you 404 page. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @BroiSatse thanks for comment. So there is nothing in the inspector console. It shows in Network that it loads page (e.g. /foo) with status code 200. But there is no content as the page is blank, only js files like analytics are loaded. So without any error. Maybe you are right, maybe it is index.html but without components loaded because of the wrong paths. But there is one weird problem. If it is index.html, it should change (redirect) URL in the browser from www.example.com/foo to www.example.com, right?

Comment: I wanted to say, that it stays on the wrong page e.g. www.example.com/foooo , but it is not redirected. And in Network there is not www.example.com which is loaded with 200 but www.example.com/foooo which is loaded with 200.

Comment: Hmmm, it's really odd that it returns 200. Not sure if that will help, but I've never seens `$uri/` in try_files before, check if it works without it. If not, check nginx access logs for anything odd.

Comment: Thank you @BroiSatse . If I add { path: '*', component: Home } to my router then it shows my website but the URL is still wrong and is not redirected to clean form =>  "www.example.com" but with dummy text after / (e.g. www.example.com/foooo). I checked error.log and also access.log but no errors.

Comment: Well in this case you either want to display 404 page or redirect to home. THe fact is that your index is being fetched by nginx and the issue is now with your Vue routes.